# C++ : The second time calling a function, but still affect my previous pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, return

I have a custom function which will return an Array Object.

I call the function in main() like below

```
int * FirstPointer = customFunction(123456);
```

but when use the function again

```
int * SecondPointer = customFunction(23);
```

it will affect my FirstPointer , which push in the returning array from second time i call the function to FirstPointer.

Why???

this is my custom function

```
//Description : integerSplitter(int x) function take in integer value 
//              and return an array object that contain the integer value ONE digit by ONE digit in array object.
//              !! The returned array object is zero-base.
//Example       : int* myObjectPointerName = integerSplitter(8912341379)
//              cout<<myObjectPointerName[0]<<myObjectPointerName[3];
//Creator     : kent.jr@me.com

int* integerSplitter(int x) { 

    int myInteger = x;
    myInteger = x;

    int myIntegerCounter = 0;
    myIntegerCounter = 0;

    int myDivider = 1;
    myDivider = 1;

    while(myInteger>=1) { 
        myInteger /= 10;
        myIntegerCounter++;
    }

    //for most of the compiler
    int* myIntegerArray;
    myIntegerArray = new int[myIntegerCounter];

    /*
    //for LLVM compiler
    int myIntegerArray[myIntegerCounter];
    */
    /*
    //for GCC Compiler
    //const int constMyIntegerCounter = myIntegerCounter;
    int* myIntegerArray = new int[ constMyIntegerCounter ];
    */

    myInteger = x;
    while(myIntegerCounter >= 1) {
        myIntegerCounter--;
        myIntegerArray[myIntegerCounter] = (myInteger/myDivider)%10;
        myDivider *= 10;
    }


    //The above while statement will automatically carry out the below statement
    //....
    //....
    //myIntegerArray[0] = (myInteger/10000000)%10;
    //myIntegerArray[1] = (myInteger/1000000)%10;
    //myIntegerArray[2] = (myInteger/100000)%10;
    //myIntegerArray[3] = (myInteger/10000)%10;
    //myIntegerArray[4] = (myInteger/1000)%10;
    //myIntegerArray[5] = (myInteger/100)%10;
    //myIntegerArray[6] = (myInteger/10)%10;
    //myIntegerArray[7] = (myInteger/1)%10;

    return myIntegerArray;
}
```

Comment: What does your `customFunction()` do?

Comment: It depends on what customFunction() does.  Can you post more code?

Comment: Please post the body of `customFunction`.

Answer (score 3):

Because the function is returning a pointer to a static int array (in other words, the pointer returned is the *same* memory address each time).  You need to fix the `cusctomFunction` to return a newly allocated array each time instead.

Comment: Good guess, be interesting to see if this turns out to be the answer.

Comment: i come from objective-c , i am new on c++ , can demonstrate to me how is that work?

Comment: How are you using the resulting arrays once they're returned?  You don't describe **how** they're being used or how they're "affecting" the first array returned.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that what you are trying to do can be achieved with pure C++, so having different code paths for different compilers is not really a good idea. The next thing is that you should tell us under which compiler this is failing.

I can tell you that in the LLVM version it will surely fail, as you are returning a pointer into the first element of a local array, which becomes invalid right after the return statement. The GCC and *most others* should be working though.

Now, I would recommend that instead of using plain arrays you create a vector internally and return it. It will save you from the pain of having to manually manage the memory (if you dynamically allocate the array) or other issues like the one you are facing.

Comment: due to this is college assignment , so i figure out some problem when i compile the code in different machines(mac-CodeRunner and pc-Visio)

Comment: @KentLeo: The fact that what you are trying to do fails in some computers should be a hint that it is not the *best* approach. Try to read the error messages and warnings and interpret what they mean and how they relate to your problem. For an assignment you should be able to compile in all compilers with no warnings with the highest warning settings.

Comment: ya , now the way i never comment it out is able to be compile in both mac and pc, the LLVM way is my first try then i find out cannot use in Visio Studio but can use in Mac,therefore i'm using the classic way which i got from google.

Comment: ... and the question still stands... which of the versions of your code is showing the behavior in the question?

Comment: the above with comment //for most of the compiler

Answer (score 0):

What does your `customFunction()` do/return exactly? If the returned address is always the same, both of your pointers will naturally point to the same memory location.